# What will I need in order to create an Android App that has users connecting with each other? (Registration & Log in)

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I want to build an app that allows users to register and then log in. I understand how to build the visual UI but I don't understand how I can get the code to work. I know I need to have a database that does authentication but how do I implement that with the Android SDK? Do I use MYSQL or some other database? Does anyone know any books that would help? Could someone please guide me? How about logging in with Facebook, how do I implement that? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are many examples on this, here is one (also describes some theory): http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Wow, someone asks a question to learn and the question gets shut down. What a great way to inspire beginners to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an app back-end. Look at this [Building app back-end](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html?m=1) article on registration and login users to your application. Or if you have a web server, you can build your own back-end using MySQL and any language of your choice.